# How do I untar a tar file containing the tar program?

Tags: tar

I have downloaded tar-latest.tar.gz from gnu.  I have unzipped it; now I have to untar it. But how can I do that, when the only tar program I have is the one in tar-latest?

Comment: You should download some tar unpacker for your platform. What is your platform (OS: Linux/Windows)?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: jerry, use 7zip - http://www.7-zip.org/download.html - it is free and capable of opening tar archives; has both command-line and gui. Step-by-step with images: http://www.simplehelp.net/2015/08/11/how-to-open-tar-gz-files-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

tar -xvf filename.tar

Reference : http://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/

Comment: I tried tar -xvf  <filename>.tar; didn't help.  It replied that tar was not a recognized command. etc. I am using Windows 10, and maybe tar doesn't come with it.

Comment: If you are using windows, please install 7zip.

Answer (score 0):

You can download tar for windows not packed in tar archive from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm

```
  Binaries      Setup       1331695     3 October 2003
```

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/tar-bin.php

or tar for ms-dos (exe): http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.12.msdos.exe

or package which includes tar: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

or any freeware archiver capable of opening tar archives: 7-zip.org, peazip.org

(Best and easier way is 7-zip.org or peazip.org)